# Angular2: Property binding permission not used by any directive on an embedded template

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I have create one directives in angular2. but, not working and return error template parse.

**my directives :**

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[permission]' })
export class PermissionDirective {
  constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private _cookie:CookieService, 
    ) {}
  @Input() set permission(_user_type: any) {
    this.viewContainer.clear();

    // let _type = this._cookie.get("_type");
    // if (_user_type == _type) {
    //   this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    // } else {
    //   this.viewContainer.clear();
    // }
  }
}
```

**Html code:**

```
<li>
     <a *permission="type" routerLink="/users/list"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Users</a>
</li>
```

**Console error log:**

```
error_handler.js:45 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'permission' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
            </li>
            <li>
                <a [ERROR ->][permission]="'2'" routerLink="/users/list"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Users</a>
            "): LeftMenuComponent@38:19
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding the Directive to the app module as a declaration?

```
import { PermissionDirective } from './permissions.directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [PermissionDirective],
    exports: [PermissionDirective]
})

export class PermissionsModule {}
```